# PHP login script not "doing anything"

Tags: php

I've recently started resuming my "hobby" of web development and returned to PHP. I've managed to get ahead pretty far even though I still feel like my (previously non existent) skills are a bit rusty. I've looked at this code for quite a while and cannot figure out why this isn't working. This code used to work so I'm pretty sure I must have deleted something or I am not noticing something important.

Either way this is my current PHP code
The result is that when I login, I stay on the same page and it basically seems like nothing happens. Except the page just refreshes:

```
function login($db){ 
if(!isset($_SESSION['user']) || !isset($_SESSION['user']['username'])){
    echo "
        <form  method='post' class='logform'>
            <input type='text' class='textlog' placeholder='Username' name='formLoginUser' id='formLoginUser' onkeypress='validateboth(event)' REQUIRED><br><br>
            <input type='password' class='textlog' placeholder='Password' id='formLoginPassword' name='formLoginPassword' REQUIRED><br><br>
            <div class='logcheck'>
                <input type='submit' class='login_bot transparent' value='Login' name='formLoginSubmit' style='float:left;'>
                <a class='login_bot transparent' href='index.php?page=createuser' style='float:left; margin-left:5px;'>Create account</a>
                <a class='login_bot transparent' href='index.php?page=forgotpassword' style='float:left; margin-left:5px;'>Forgotten password</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    ";
    if(isset($_POST['formLoginSubmit'])){
        if(empty($_POST['formLoginUser'])){
            $_SESSION['msg']['warning'][] = "Fill in!!"; 
        if(empty($_POST['formLoginPassword'])){
            $_SESSION['msg']['warning'][] = "Password missing!!"; 
        }
        if(empty($_SESSION['msg']['warning'])){
            $username = $db->real_escape_string($_POST['formLoginUser']);
            $password = encrypt(md5($_POST['formLoginPassword']));
            $sql = "select * from users
                                    where 
                                        username = '{$username}' 
                                    and 
                                        password = '{$password}'
                                    ";
            $sqlQuery = $db->query($sql) or die($db->error);
            $intQuery = $sqlQuery->num_rows;
            if($intQuery == true){
                $sqlFetch = $sqlQuery->fetch_object();
                $_SESSION['user']['username'] = $sqlFetch->username;
                $_SESSION['user']['id'] = $sqlFetch->user_id;
                $_SESSION['user']['level'] = $sqlFetch->user_level;
                header('location: index.php?page=home');
                $_SESSION['msg']['warning'][] = "logged in";
            }
        }else{
            header('location: index.php?page=home');
            $_SESSION['msg']['warning'][] = "wrong details";

        }
    }
}

}
}
```

I know it's not a problem with the DB, I can successfully register an account and have it appear in the DB.

Edit: Yes, I am redirecting to the same page how ever - on that page I'm calling a function to display a message depending on whether the login was successful or not.  The point is, I'm not logged in at all.

The function to call the login is:

```
<div id="login-content">
    <?php login($db); ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: In both situations you are redirecting to the same link

Comment: where\how do you call the function?

Comment: You're also redirecting and adding to `$_SESSION` afterwards.

Comment: @andrewsi With no `exit;` after the `header()` that actually is not a problem, although it seems logically wrong

Comment: ifthis is one page simply removing the function could be all you need

Comment: I'm using one index.php page for the entire "website" so to speak.  So it's essential for me to call the function in that page. I'm working on learning how to use functions properly and I believe this  was/is a good way.                                                                                                      Basically when you go to register you get: 
 "index.php?page=createuser". I Also edited my OP to include the calling of the function.

Answer (score 0):

change `if($intQuery == true)` with `if($intQuery >0)` because num_rows returns integer as name of the function defines it.
also your query is vulnerable to sql injection and real_escape_string is not secure method for escaping injection. there is a good article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) for preventing sql injection.

Tip: you can jump in an out of your php code  with `?><?php` and type your desired html in between to prevent wired bugs and have a clear code.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, still gives me the same result. Also, yeah..I figured as much -  was going to look into making it safe from SQL injection later.